# Designing a circuit that will reset the proccessor

Tags: digital-logic, design, microprocessor

In the book *The Intel Microprocessors Family: Hardware and Software, Principles and Applications* chapter 8, page 307, question 30:

> design a circuit that will reset the processor if a NMI occurs while
>   the 8088 is being held.

- 8088 checks for NMI after finishing every instruction.
- I can detect if 8088 is held if HOLDA signal = 1.
- I think that I can reset the 8088 by making RESET input signal = 1
  for more than 4T.

Truth Table:
[image]

But I don't know how to convert that to a circuit. In fact I have no idea how to do that.

Any help?

Comment: What do you have so far. Can you detect an NMI? Can you detect whether the 8088 is held? Can you reset the 8088?

Comment: 8088 checks for NMI after finishing every instruction. I can detect if 8088 is held if HOLDA signal = 1. I think that I can reset the 8088 by making RESET input signal = 1 for more than 4T. But I don't know how to convert that to a circuit.

Comment: Can YOU detect an NMI? Can you make the truth table for the circuit that you can't yet make?

Comment: @ammarx Please, put all this information in the question. As much as info you put in question, easiest, quickest and better will be the answer.

Comment: @Butzke I wrote the question as it is in the textbook. No information are missed.

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen I made this truth table :
http://cl.ly/image/0A0U0I2m2c3t

Comment: OK, now look at your truth table and get the truth tables of some common logic gates. Does it match any of those? Depending on the level of your course, there might also be some timing aspect involved. Judge for yourself what is expected.

Comment: Obviously, RESET represents an AND gate. But we need a clock for timing, right?

Comment: That's up to you to infer from the other information you have (in the book you mention).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As the above truth table says that when the hold , hlda and nmi signal goes high then you want to make the reset signal high. For this you can install a interrupt handler for NMI and when the isr occurs then make the io pin high and then u will have all the status at muc pins.
Then put a three input and gate and connect hold, hlda and the isr output pin to the and gate and connect the output of that gate to the reset pin and the controller will reset when all the inputs to the gate will go high.